# Is there a specific package for HTML output to render to a word document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have an interactive document that renders from a Shiny Application. The report contains tables from the DT package with formatting. When I run the application locally, it provides the word document along with the HTML output. However, after I deploy the app to RStudio Connect, it will not render the HTML output (errors out). Is there a particular package from my local library that allows the HTML output?

The error log from RStudio Connect is below.

```
Warning: Error in : Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
05/30 15:36:18.075
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
05/30 15:36:18.075
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
05/30 15:36:18.075
your rmarkdown file:
```

Again, the HTML output is not a problem locally and it is my belief that a specific package not being installed on connect is the culprit.

```
Server file: Linked to an action button in UI File.
output$scorecard <- downloadHandler(
        # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
        filename = "Supplier_Scorecard.docx",
        content = function(file) {
            # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
            # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
            # can happen when deployed).
            #tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "scorecard.Rmd")
            #file.copy("scorecard.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

            # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
            params <- list(supplier = input$which.supplier, names = input$supplier.name, street = input$supplier.street,
                           citystate = input$supplier.citystate, datas = scarred, one = Two[1], two = Two[2], three = Two[3])

            # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
            # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
            # from the code in this app).
            rmarkdown::render("scorecard.Rmd", output_file = file,
                              word_document(reference_docx = "styles-reference-word.docx",
                                            fig_height = 4),
                              params = params,
                              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
            )
        }
    )
```

YAML

```
title: "Supplier Scorecard"
output: word_document
params:
  citystate: NA
  datas: NA
  date: !r format(Sys.Date(), "%b-%d-%Y")
  names: NA
  one: NA
  street: NA
  supplier: NA
  three: NA
  two: NA
```

When I run the shiny application locally I have no issues. Renders to a word document and the HTML output can be seen.

Again, within RStudio Connect it errors out to the following message in my logs.

```
Warning: Error in : Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
05/30 15:36:18.075
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
05/30 15:36:18.075
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
05/30 15:36:18.075
your rmarkdown file:
```